# SQL - building a certain query (intersect between two conditions)

Tags: sql, mysqli

i have a table that has two columns (that are relevant to my question) - Companies and Products.
It is providing me information about which companies use several Products.

For instance, lets say i want to retrieve all the companies that using Microsoft Office, i will query with a condition - product = Microsoft Office.

now, my question - 
I need to build a query that will retrieve me all the companies that are using **two** products, not just one.
How should i build the query? 
I think it should sort of use subquery maybe? because the SQL need to do two queries - one for each product i want, and than intersect both queries in order to find the companies that are in both lists...

Thanks alot for the helpers!

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as well formatted text (not images). Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are no duplicates in the table, you could do something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), <name of the company column> FROM <table name> GROUP BY <name of the company column> HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

**EDIT**
To figure out who is using two specific products, use this instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), <name of the company column> FROM <table name> WHERE <name of product column> = '<name of 1st product>' OR <name of product column> = '<name of second product>' GROUP BY <name of the company column> HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Comment: And also i should add - WHERE prudct = a OR product = b, right?

Comment: Oh. I assumed you just wanted to find out who is using 2 products, regardless of which product it is.

Comment: ha, alright. awesome! understood it... thanks alot! and just for my general knowledgee - is there another way to get to the desired results?

Comment: You could also use IN, in case you want to have more than 2 specific products: SELECT COUNT(*), <name of the company column> FROM <table name> GROUP BY <name of the company column> HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 WHERE <name of product column> IN ('<product 1>', '<product 2>', ..., '<product n>');

Comment: WHERE clause goes before GROUP BY, but valid comments

Answer (score 1):

Thomas is right and to add the two products:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*),
    <name of the company column>,
    <name of the product column>
FROM
    <table name>
GROUP BY
    <name of the company column>
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 2
    AND <name of the product column> IN ('product1', 'product2');
```